# Abrir página de Login en ventana modal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un WebForm con un formulario de Login, al que quiero abrir automáticamente si mi variable de sesién está vacía. ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de hacerlo? Dejo el código del `formLogin`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="formLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="formLogin" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap (2).css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
            /*z-index: 10000;*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelModal" runat="server" Style="background: white;" Height="325px" Width="400px">
            <div>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="box-header">Iniciar Sesion</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid well">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span4">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" WatermarkText="Email" TargetControlID="txtEmail" />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server" WatermarkText="Contraseña" TargetControlID="txtPassw" />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassw" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="errorDatos" class="control-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" Visible="False" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="Entrar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" Text="Registrarse" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnSignUp_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución a la cuestión presentada es leer la variable de sesión cada 5 segundos (este tiempo es a modo de ejemplo) es con el siguiente código de Javascript:

```js
function revisaVariableSesion() {
console.log('Aquí va la lógica para revisar variable de sesión cada 5 segundos');
} 
var interval = setInterval(
function () {
revisaVariableSesion();
}, 5000);
```

Ahora, en la función `revisaVariableSesion` validaremos el contenido de la variable de la sesión con el código redireccionando al `Logout.aspx` para eliminar todos los rastros de la sesión actual:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function revisaVariableSesion() {
        var sesionValida = '<%= Session["sesionValida"] %>';
        if(!sessionValida)
            window.location = "LogOut.aspx";
    } 
    var interval = setInterval(
        function () {
        revisaVariableSesion();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

En caso de que la sesión no sea válida, realizamos por completo el `logout` en la página `LogOut.aspx` y luego que redireccione al `Login.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Expires = -1000;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
}
```